# Combinatorics - problem about combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The key has different sockets and different locations. The key has 8 possible sockets. How many locations are required to produce at least a million different keys?

I thought that its 1,000,000 / 64 
because on every one socket and same locations theres 8 keys 
so on 64 locations theres 1000000 keys.
but im sure im wrong..

unfortunately i dont have answer because its from my test today.

Comment: In any case, it isn't totally clear to me what sockets and locations mean in this context... but if the question were rephrased in terms of strings... remember that a string of length $n$ with $k$ available characters has $k^n$ possibilities.  If "sockets" are an analogy to characters and "locations" an anology to positions, you are asked to find the smallest $n$ such that $8^n > 1000000$.  This is a routine algebra problem involving logarithms.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you -  ill make it clear for you - sockets means 8 different types  thickness of the holes in the key. locations meant the location of one socket at the key, think about your home key. [thats what i understand]

Comment: In which case under most interpretations I suppose my original interpretation is correct.  As for completing the problem it should be trivial if you have a calculator.  If not, then the numbers given are very kind to estimation, remember that $2^{10}\approx 1000$ and so $2^{20}\approx 1000000$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah we had calculator. so youre saying the answer according to you is approximately 6.64 which is 7 locations? (8^6.64) ≈ 1,000,000